# To convert an Excel file to CSV and then move that data from CSV to oracle database

Tags: oracle, excel, csv, vbscript

I have an excel sheet which I want to have it in CSV format and then that data from CSV should be loaded into a table in oracle database.

I have a VBscript to convert the excel file to CSV but the format of that excel sheet is a bit different so the CSV file is not being populated correctly. I am attaching a link to download that sample excel sheet.[Excel sheet](http://www.filedropper.com/auto_1)

If you notice the red colored text are the fields and their respective data is on the next cell. FOr example for heading Date data is 1/1/2000. Now when I convert this using that vbscript, i am attaching a link here to download that csv.

I want to strip all of those commas and that Column 1 (length 10) and all others to be removed. Only the heading and its data should be present in the CSV file. Can you please help me with this.

Thanks in advance. VBscript code is here :-

```
WorkingDir = "C:\Users\vijaywp\Desktop"
Extension = ".XLS"

Dim fso, myFolder, fileColl, aFile, FileName, SaveName
Dim objExcel,objWorkbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(WorkingDir)
Set fileColl = myFolder.Files

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts= False

For Each aFile In fileColl
ext = Right(aFile.Name,4)
If UCase(ext) = UCase(extension) Then
'open excel
FileName = Left(aFile,InStrRev(aFile,"."))
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(aFile)
SaveName = FileName & "csv"
objWorkbook.SaveAs SaveName, 23
objWorkbook.Close 
End If  
Next

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set fileColl = Nothing
```

After this conversion, I want that CSV data to be loaded into Oracle databse table. Please help.

Here is the link to the expected CSV output :- [Expected CSV Output](http://www.filedropper.com/autoexpectedoutput)

Comment: Could you please share resulting CSV as you wish it to have? There's too much data in your file, and it's not clear what exactly you want...

Comment: Have you thought about just doing this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315504/tricks-for-generating-sql-statements-in-excel

Comment: I will share the CSV the way I want it.

Comment: Hello, I have attached a link for the expected CSV format that I need. Please check and let me know when can be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me with this. I am trying but unable to get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom format in your CSV file, then read the excel row by row, column by column, and write the data to CSV as you choose to do it.

If commas in columns are the only problem, then use a option to double quote the column texts so that the comma in there does not pose a problem.

Comment: I am actually new to this. Can you please help

Comment: Help with what? Reading excel cell by cell and writing it back into a file? Net would give you tons of examples on how to read excel cell by cell.

Comment: I did searched but nothing much I could get.

Answer (score 0):

This may be disappointing, however, going to csv first may simply be unnecessary.  You have Excel, you want data into an Oracle table. Let's say our Oracle table "member_list" has three columns: Name, Phone, City.  Our Excel Data has Name in column A, Phone in column B, City in column C. Our headings are in Row1 data starts in Row2.
     In column D2 enter the following formula:
     ="into member_list ("&$A$1&","&$B$1&","&$C$1&") VALUES("&A2&",'"&B2&"','"&C2&")"
     Copy this same statement to each data row.
Back in SQLDeveloper Type:  **Insert All**
Follow by copying all your "D" column  "into statements"
into SQLDeveloper. Finally type:
    **Select * from dual;**

Execute and you have now inserted all your Excel data into Oracle.