# query SQL in VBA excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba, xquery-sql

i connect my excel to MS SQL and i want excute the query :

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany' AND (City='Berlin' OR City='München');
```

and its work fine

i want use it on vba:

```
Set rs=c.Execute(“SELECT * FROM Customers" & _ 
WHERE Country='Germany' AND (City='Berlin' OR City='München');”)"
```

now how can set VAR inside the query:
**Country** and **City** something like range("A1").value or declare variable dim city as string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tricks for generating SQL statements in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315504/tricks-for-generating-sql-statements-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. :

```vb
Dim country, city

country = Range("A1").Value
city = Range("B1").Value

Set rs = c.Execute("SELECT * FROM Customers " & _ 
                   " WHERE Country='" & country  & "'" & _
                   " AND City='" & city & "'")
```

Comment: so the var should be between  '" & var & "'